# How to store an object that is retrievable from the client-side in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, express, static

Beginner question: I built a simple draggable to-do list that caches the state in a single object (tasks, containers and index) - currently, it's storing it in local storage. I am working on the server side using express and node.js, but I am confused as to where I would simply store the object. Would a database like mongodb be a good choice...or is there an even simpler option? I assume I can keep the project static and have the server side just receive and serve up JSON? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to integrate it with backend server, it is actually a good idea to store the object in a database. The benefit is, you can still maintain the state of your to-do-list no matter on which machine you are logging in. If you access your to-do-list app from the browser of your smartphone or desktop, they both still point to a single source of truth, which is your database. Think of it as a Trello board that is in-sync on every device. In your database, you may record the task status, task ID, description, etc. If you want to go further, you can group this information per user, so every user will have their own to-do-list. (which is not possible if you rely on conventional local storage). With database, you can extend the functionality beyond simple to-do-list. Alternatively, you may consider a much simpler solution by recording the object as JSON file and storing it in your server. This solution is feasible albeit limited flexibility.

I would recommend MongoDB Atlas and Firebase Realtime Database as both are beginner friendly and easy to use. Both are free-of-charge on limited usage and hosted in the cloud.

Comment: I suppose should have also asked (but I didn't want to convolute the question)...since I am going to go the mongodb route. Can I still have my client side serve up the javascript, css and html....and the server side just serve up the data I need...or does the server then have to serve the whole page with something like ejs?

Comment: Yes, you can still use the existing client side JS, CSS, and HTML. The client-side JS will call the server-side API to fetch/ update data to database. Now the backend server only acts as mediator between client and database and handles data exchange, typically in JSON format.

Comment: Or, if you want to go for EJS route, the client-side JS, CSS, and HTML can be merged to server code. This time, server will not only act as data mediator, but will also serve HTML, CSS, and JS. The HTML file is rendered from the EJS template and is sent to client together with CSS, JS, and other asset files, usually stored in `public` folder of your server. Note that every interaction with database is done in the server, so there is no risk of leaking sensitive information, such as database credentials.

Comment: Each has its own pros and cons. If you have dedicated client, the transaction is mainly JSON data. However, it comes with a cost of exposing our original client JS code. If you opt for the server-side route, you have more control what to put in the public JS file, what HTML content to render; probably a better option if you take security seriously. Because server-side rendering handles the heavy lifting, the response time may be slower than having dedicated client. Of course it is not the only pros and cons, but I hope it gives you a big picture and helps you to decide which path to take.

Comment: This is super helpful and clear - thanks for even explaining the trade-offs of each structure. Much appreciated again, Dave. This is exactly what I was looking for.